# Passing an exception up the calling chain

Tags: java

Was hoping for an explanation as to what it means to pass an exception up the calling chain by declaring the exception in my methods throws clause and why I would want to do that.

Here is an example of my understanding of throwing own exception.

```
public class ExceptionThrow {
    char[] charArray = new char[] { 'c', 'e', 'a', 'd' };

    void checkArray() throws ABException {
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
            switch (charArray[i]) {
            case 'a':
                throw new ABException();
            case 'b':
                throw new ABException();// creating the instance of the
                                        // exception anticipated
            default:
                System.out.println(charArray[i] + " is not A or a B");

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExceptionThrow et = new ExceptionThrow();

        try {
            et.checkArray();
        } catch (ABException ab) {
            System.out.println(ab.getMessage() + " An exception did actually occur");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("This block will always execute");
        }

    }
}

class ABException extends Exception {
}
```

How would I pass the exception 'up the calling chain'?

regards
Arian

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The "calling chain", also commonly known as "stack trace", is the list of all nested method calls leading to a single line of execution. In your case, its depth is 2 : `main` calls `checkArray`, but there can be dozens of methods.

When an exception occurs in the code, it interrupts the current method and gives the control back to the previous method on the stack trace. If this method can handle the exception (with a `catch`), the `catch` will be executed, the exception will stop bubbling up. If not, the exception will bubble up the stack trace. Ultimately, if it arrives in the `main` and the `main` cannot handle it, the program will stop with an error.

In your specific case, the `throw new ABException()` creates and throws an `ABException` that interrupts the `checkArray` method. The exception is then caught in your main with `catch(ABException ab)`. So according to your question, you can say that this code passes the exception 'up the calling chain'.

There are many more things to say, notably related to checked/unchecked exceptions. If you have some more specific questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: +1 for the clear explanation. I have one small thing to add, if you would like to see the stacktrace of an exception you can call its `printStackTrace()` method, e.g. `try { ... } catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: THelper, I am not saying you are wrong, but I think its bad practice to use e.printStackTrace() in these (bubbling up the exception) situations. Its okay to use it for testing and stuff. Because this leaves unwanted stack trace in your log files. Especially if the exception is being handled by the upper layer, why pollute logs with stack traces which has no meaning in the current context.

Answer (score 4):

First, you'll have to add `throws ABException` to the `main` method and then either delete the block that catches the exception or rethrow it after logging

```
throw ab;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for example by not catching it in `main()`, but passing it to the piece of logic that called `main()`. In this case, it's trivial, as `main()` is your program's entry point...

You could also rewrite your method

```
void checkArray() throws ABException {
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        check(charArray[i]);
    }
}

void check(char c) throws ABException {
    switch (c) {
        case 'a':
            throw new ABException();
        case 'b':
            throw new ABException();// creating the instance of the
                                    // exception anticipated
        default:
            System.out.println(c + " is not A or a B");
    }
}
```

Now it becomes more clear how `checkArray()` "passes the exception from `check()` up the calling chain"

Comment: WHat if this is a system with multiple components and we don't want to pass the entire stack trace over the wire but bubble up some relevant information?