# How to continue execution of a try catch statement in java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Try-Catch-Continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794369/java-try-catch-continue)

I'm reading in information from a text file and I want my code to throw an exception if there is an invalid type being read. However, I can't figure out how to have my program continue after an exception has been found

```
    while(input.hasNext()) {
        try{

        type = input.next();
        name = input.next();
        year = input.nextInt();


        } catch(InputMismatchException ex)
          {
            //System.out.println("** Error: Invalid input **");
            //code to make program continue

          }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either just let the thread leave the `catch` block - code execution will continue after that. If you want to skip the code after the `catch` block, you can use the `continue` keyword within a `while` loop...

If you want to retrieve a `year` after retrieving the `name` failed with an exception, then you will have to put a `try ... catch` around each `input.next...()` statement. You cannot restart execution at the point the exception has been thrown.